# Авторизация oAuth2 в Яндекс Маркете

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth, oauth2, яндекс-маркет

Есть google app script, который обращается к сервису Yandex Market и загружает каталог товаров.

1. Создала аккаунт на yandex.ru.
2. Зарегистрировалась в магазине Yandex.Market и завела пару товаров.
3. Зарегистрировала oAuth-приложение, получила его:

```
ID=820ca53b10f24058b2534cf6e1f28a5f
```

4. Создала отладочный токен через [сервис](https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=820ca53b10f24058b2534cf6e1f28a5f).
5. Получаю ответы. Все отлично.

Стала передавать скрипт клиенту для его магазина.

1. Попросила его тоже дать доступ к приложению `ID=820ca53b10f24058b2534cf6e1f28a5f`.
2. Подставила его токен и его `campaignId` магазина:

```
  var options = {'method' : method , //'get',
                  'contentType': 'application/json'}
  options.headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_token="' + oauth_token +'", oauth_client_id="' + oauth_client_id+ '"'}  ;

  var params = {};
  setParam(params, 'page_token', pageToken );

  if (setParamsFunc)    
    setParamsFunc (params, ...args)

  var urlWB = buildUrl(url.format(campaignId), params);

  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlWB, options);
```

3. Получаю ошибку:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://api.partner.market.yandex.ru returned code 403. 
Truncated server response: 
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Access denied"},"errors":
[{"code":"FORBIDDEN","message":"Access denied"}],"status":"ERROR"} 
(use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

Что не так? Как получить моему приложению доступ к чужому кабинету YandexMarket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае помогла поддержка Яндекс.

1. Необходимо было создать **новый** аккаунт на Яндекс
2. Добавить его в сотрудники магазина, добавить расширенные права (менеджер+финансы)
3. Создать под этим юзером новое приложение на https://oauth.yandex.ru/
4. Получить новый токен

После этого, все заработало